# How to install ejabberd on Linode server using SSH

Tags: 14.04, ssh, ejabberd

I have a hosting purchased at linode at Latest Ubuntu set-up on it all the updates and upgrades installed.

I am trying to install **ejabberd** on linode server. But I am facing some problems.

Things I have tried so far.

1. Installing Default ejabberd version provided by Ubuntu

> Tried to install **ejabberd 2.1.11** provided by **sudo apt-get install ejabberd** although latest version is **16.08**. Edited **.conf** file to add user but service isn't starting and couldn't register user from Command Prompt.

2. Tried installing **ejabberd 16.08.run** file

> Tried using chmod command. Setup completed successfully but ejabberd service isn't starting. Tried to setup ejabberd by editing config files but ejabberd service isn't starting.

Can someone provide proper giude to install and setup ejabberd. I have a root access on linode so authentication will not be a problem.